# C++ class constructor throwing an exception

Tags: c++, class, exception, constructor

Lets consider having a ***class*** with a ***constructor*** throwing an ***exception*** like following:

```
class Class
{
    public:
        Class(type argument)
        {
            if (argument == NULL)
            {
                throw std::exception("Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: argument");
            }

            // Instructions
        }
    private:
        // Properties
}
```

Since the ***class*** ***constructor*** might throw an ***exception*** we cannot declare an ***object*** directly.

```
Class obj(argument); // Harmful
```

Which means the ***constructor*** must be called must be using a ***try/catch***

```
try
{
    Class obj(argument);
}
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that we can only use the ***object*** inside the ***try*** block. The only way to use it outside of the ***try*** block is to declare a **Class*** ***pointer*** then use the ***new*** keyword to construct a new ***object*** then assign it's address to the previous ***pointer***.

```
Class* pObj;

try
{
    pObj = new Class(argument);
}
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

So what is the standard way to define the previous ***class*** in order to create instances without using ***pointers*** or dynamic memory allocation?

***Thank you in advance***

Comment: If you use your pointer approach and the constructor throws you can catch the exception and still access the pointer outside the `try`-`catch` block.  But what now?  You have a pointer but no object!  The purpose of exceptions is not to wrap every statement that could eventually throw inside a `try`-`catch` block and thus linearize the control flow again.  Exceptions were invented to allow just the opposite: Break out of the normal control flow in exceptional situations (such as after erroneously passing a NULL pointer to a constructor that doesn't accept one).

Comment: If I remember correctly, I saw somewhere that this is not a real good desing. What you should do it therefore to create it without exceptions and the check if it has breen created correctly.

Comment: That's not right since an unhanded exception will break the program.

Comment: If you don't like exceptions but prefer traditional error handling, then just do so.  But if you design your functions to throw exceptions (which I prefer to do) then don't afterwards fight against that machinery.  An exception thrown by a constructor that was passed an invalid argument *should* ([§ 22](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/toc)) “break” the program.  (Don't pass invalid arguments, if you want your program to continue.)

Comment: If I remember correctly, standard `std::exception` does not have a constructor taking a `const char*` as argument.

Comment: Probably wants `std::runtime_error`

Comment: Keep in mind that creating a local variable rather than using dynamic allocation means you're using the stack, and the variable will leave scope and no longer exist when the function returns.  Given a try/catch block can surround all the function's processing, there's no necessary lessening of scope when using a try/catch - the object is just as useful as it could possible be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since the class constructor might throw an exception we cannot declare
>   an object directly.

Yes, you can. You only need to put it in a try block if you actually have a plan to deal with an exception right there, in the function. If you don't have such a plan, then just let the exception propogate (though you should catch it eventually, just to provide a report if nothing else).

But, assuming you do have a plan to handle the exception right there in the function, then the solution is simple.

```
try {
    Class obj(argument);
    // use obj here, inside the try block
}
catch(...) { ... }

// not here, outside the try block
```

Edit: By your comment below, either you are misunderstanding me, or I am misunderstanding you. Perhaps a concrete exaqmple is required. Let's say that this is your function which uses your class:

```
void Foobar(type argument)
{
    Class obj(argument);
    obj.method1(1,2,3);
    obj.method2(3,4);
    int x = Wizbang(obj);
    gobble(x);    
}
```

Now, you want to handle the exception that the `Class` constructor might throw. What I'm suggesting is putting all of that junk in the function, into a try block, thusly:

```
void Foobar(type argument)
{
    try
    {
        Class obj(argument);
        obj.method1(1,2,3);
        obj.method2(3,4);
        int x = Wizbang(obj);
        gobble(x);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you can't do this, please explain why. You've said *"I need access to use the object later"*, but you've provided no reason why *"later"* cannot mean *"later within the same try block where the object was created"*. As such, your requirements are incomplete.

Comment: @cell: If he did, then he certainly didn't provide any reason why the option should be dismissed.

Comment: When I said I can't I meant if an exception has thrown the program will explode. Creating the object inside the try/catch is not an option since I need access to use the object later.

Comment: @rullof: Where, exactly, do you need to use the object? And why, exactly, can that code where you need to use it not be inside the try block?

Comment: @rullof, Here's the thing. If the object was created successfully, it can be safely used. If not, it cannot be safely used. Leaving the try block implies that the object was not created successfully. With this in mind, using that object is not good.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not (reasonably) possible.  Suppose there were some method of doing what you want, that is, creating an object obj of type Class that was still in scope outside any relevant try{}catch{} construct used to handle exceptions in the constructor.  Thw question to ask yourself is, if an exception were to be thrown during construction of the obj, and you somehow handled the exception and then execution were to continue in the block where the obj was still in scope, what exactly would the obj contain?  It was never constructed, so just what would be in the obj????